# Find the specific hypothesis in binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, classification

Let

$$A+ = \{(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)\}$$

and

$$A- = \{(2,2), (-2,2), (2,-2), (-2,-2)\}$$

represent the *positive* and *negative* training instances respectively. The hypothesis space used in this binary classification problem is

$$H = \{ All\ axis\ paralled\ rectangles \} ⊂ R\mathbb{^{2}}$$.

How to find the *most specific hypothesis* $hs ∈ H$ and the *version space* for this problem.  Can illustrate the version space by plotting a figure.

Find the *optimal hypothesis* $h\mathbb{^{*}} ∈ H$ and justify the answer.

Comment: This seems a good fit for the self-study tag. You also want to take a moment to read its wiki.

Comment: Dear sir, @SeanEaster, I can plot the version space, SB and GB. Like [this image](http://imgur.com/XXtVCmV). But I don't understand "optimal hypothesis" in version space and justify it.

Comment: I think your confusion is due mostly to ambiguity in the question: "Optimal" can be interpreted and defined in many ways, and it's not apparent from the question what the author meant. Might it be related to the [Bayes optimal classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Bayes_optimal_classifier)?

Comment: Dear sir, thank your response. I think "the most specific hypothesis" is also "optimal hypothesis", right? Can you give some tips about this question?

Comment: Well, again that all depends on what one means by "optimal." The most specific hypothesis will produce the fewest false positives, but will also produce the most false negatives, depending on the true target concept. But, that's one very specific definition of optimal, and one of rather arguable use. Have you fully reproduced this question from its source? It would seem that the author might be asking you to define optimal, then argue for your definition.